# UITableView - how to recognize a cancel deletion?

Tags: uitableview

After the classic swipe to delete, there are two possibilities,

> - The user has pressed the "Delete" Button, so this function is fired:
> - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
> - The user has pressed **outside** the button, so the edit state is cancelled.

Does anyone knows which function (if it exists) is fired when the editing is cancelled, or how can I catch this event? so I can do some stuff right after the deletion is cancelled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the edit state is finished, you'll know via the UITableViewDelegate method [`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3adidEndEditingRowAtIndexPath%3a)

You just need to figure out how to differentiate between a delete and a cancel. You'll know it's a delete if the data source ["`tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`" method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3acommitEditingStyle%3aforRowAtIndexPath%3a) is called.  If it isn't, then the user cancelled.